# JSONP Call to instagram web returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to make a call to this Instagram website that returns user information: https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1, so that's why I am using ajax with JSONP instead of JSON to avoid CORS problems.

This is what I do, based on the answer to [a question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'callback',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

I also tried changing to this call:

```
    $.ajax({

        url: "https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1",
        type: "POST",
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result)

        },

    });
```

And I finally tried using jsonp without ajax:

```
var $jsonp = (function(){
  var that = {};

  that.send = function(src, options) {
    var callback_name = options.callbackName || 'callback',
      on_success = options.onSuccess || function(){},
      on_timeout = options.onTimeout || function(){},
      timeout = options.timeout || 10; // sec

    var timeout_trigger = window.setTimeout(function(){
      window[callback_name] = function(){};
      on_timeout();
    }, timeout * 1000);

    window[callback_name] = function(data){
      window.clearTimeout(timeout_trigger);
      on_success(data);
    }

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = src;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }

  return that;
})();
```

And to call the function like this, but unfortunately always returns **timeout**:

```
$jsonp.send('https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1?callback=handleStuff', {
    callbackName: 'handleStuff',
    onSuccess: function(json){
        console.log('success!', json);
    },
    onTimeout: function(){
        console.log('timeout!');
    },
    timeout: 5
});
```

I have already tried many possibilities while searching here in StackOverflow or googling different questions about using JSONP none worked. Would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: The server still needs to return JSONP for this to work. [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21715747/1848744). There is a reason you can't fetch data from URLs that are not meant to be used as external API endpoints. Your alternative would be using a web server as a proxy for fetching these results.

Comment: the lesson here is - you can't beat CORS

Comment: Thanks Matt, you are right about the server returning, I intercepted the request and saw that it's sent to the server and receives a response, the only problem is the variable `data` or `result` don't contain that response because of the error.

Comment: @JaromandaX programmers never give up I am sure there is a way:)

Comment: the only way is to proxy the request via your own server, or via some third party service that provides CORS headers for non-CORS enabled services. But that's not "beating" CORS - the end server can "see" lots of requests coming from one server, and the owners can decide to block such requests anyway

Answer (score 0):

i think your JSONP url response data is not a standard jsonp data format. it is a pure json format,that is you always get a js error after you open the page.you can try to modify the url response data to a standard jsonp format,the right is JSONP_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(A JSON STRING DATA)

Comment: do you mean to change `function(data)` to `jsonp_callback_function(data)`?

Comment: no,you need to modify the return in your program code,instead of js.

Comment: you can see  the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms),you will know between  JSON and JSONP difference

Comment: still can't get the data if you could give some reproducible example would really appreciate it!