# How do I request JSON data from a separate domain and use it on my own

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

1. I am trying to use JSON data from "https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=13165" and put the data on my website.
2. I am trying to access the JSON field name "Stats" and I am trying to get the sub-field name ' \"v\" '. Here is the documentation provided by purpleair. https://docs.google.com/document/d/15ijz94dXJ-YAZLi9iZ_RaBwrZ4KtYeCy08goGBwnbCU/edit (second page)

I have my code written using a XMLHttpRequest(). It says at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) that you cant go across domains, and when I tried to follow their instructions using PHP, I got lost. I do not own the purpleair.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p id='demo'></p>
    <script src="jsonp.php">
        function reqListener() {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.stats
        }
        function loadData() {
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
            oReq.open("GET", "https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=13165");
            oReq.send();
        }
        loadData()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715620/using-jsonp-to-get-json-data-from-another-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `Stats` property is JSON-encoded *inside* the other JSON-encoded results.

Here is another way to deal with it, using the more modern `fetch` in place of XHR:

```js
const getData = () =>
  fetch('https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=13165')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json.results)
    .then(res => res.map(r => JSON.parse(r.Stats)))
    .then(res => res.map(r => r.v))

getData()
  .then(vs => document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = vs)
```

```css
#output {background: yellow; padding: .25em}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Stats v values: <span id="output"></span>
```

### Update: Explanation

A comment asked how this works.

First off, there's some unfortunate overlap in naming.  `res` or `result` or `results` is a common name for the result of a server call.  The `res` in `res => res.json()` represents that.  But then we take this object (which I called `json`, not a very good name, admittedly; it also probably should be `res`, but we have a surfeit of `res`s already) and extract its `results` property to pass to the next `.then()` call.  I also call this variable `res` in the next callback.  Finally, the last call `.then()` was stupidly named.  It should read

```js
    .then(stats => stats.map(s => s.v))
```

So it might also be written,

```js
const getData = () =>
  fetch('https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=13165')
    .then(serverResponse => serverResponse.json())
    .then(apiResultObject => apiResultObject.results)
    .then(results => results.map(result => JSON.parse(result.Stats)))
    .then(stats => stats.map(stat => stat.v))
```

All the `then`s have to do with the [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  If you're not used to it, it is definitely worth spending some time investigating.

The two `map` calls are used to convert one array into another by collecting the results of running a given function on each element.  So

```js
          results => results.map(result => JSON.parse(result.Stats))
```

means that for each element in the array `results`, we will create a new element by taking its `Stats` property and running `JSON.parse` on that value.  Then we will put all these values together in a new array.  `JSON.parse` takes the string value returned by the API and turns it into a JS object.  We need this here, even though we've done a JSON call on the response object because of the slightly unusual structure of the response where this part is double-encoded.

Similarly, this line:

```js
          stats => stats.map(stat => stat.v)
```

converts an array of `stats` objects into an array containing their `v` properties.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain what ```res.map(r => JSON.parse(r.Stats)))``` and  ```res.map(r => r.v))``` are doing? Also, What does 'r' stand for? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: @BrianWiebe: Updated with an more complete explanation.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot more sense. The ```v``` is relating to the array that was mapped. However, using the ID that I am using, I there are two JSON arrays in ```result```. How can I get rid of the second ```v``` value?

Comment: This is easier.  Untested, but it should be something like this: `...     .then(apiResultObject => apiResultObject.results[0]).then(result => JSON.parse(result.Stats)).then(stat => stat.v)`
`

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at another project I am doing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398435/how-can-i-get-data-from-a-json-file-that-is-on-a-different-domain-with-no-header

Comment: @wiebecoding: sorry, I'm on vacation for the rest of the week with no access to a computer.

Comment: No problem. Have fun @ScottSauyet.

Comment: Is it possible to get the AGE from the regular ```results[0].AGE```? I cant seem to find a way to get the value in the first place. Also, is it possible to have an if statement that does ```.then(vs => document.getElementById('GBPM').innerHTML = vs.toFixed(2))``` when the age is under 10 and to do ```.then(vs => document.getElementById('GBPM').innerHTML = "-Offline-"``` when the age is over 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can get JSON from PurpelAir like this:

```js
function reqListener() {
  // parse the the data
  var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
  // create an array from the required data (result.Stats -> watch the capital 'S')
  var mappedData = data.results.map(item => item.Stats)
  // display data
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = mappedData.join()
}

function loadData() {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  oReq.open("GET", "https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=13165");
  oReq.send();
}

loadData()
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

More about XMLHttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

I reworked your code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <!-- make ' to " in the ID-->
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <!-- no src for the script -->
  <script>
    function reqListener() {
      var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      // this myObj.stats doesn't exist (try console.log(myObj))
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.stats
      // instead try this:
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.results.map(item => item.Stats).join()
    }

    function loadData() {
      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
      oReq.open("GET", "https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=13165");
      oReq.send();
    }
    loadData()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How I tried to have the code come out as the ID 'demo', but that isnt working. I posted my new code as an edit. Any tips?

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the JSON data.

Comment: 1. The `<script>` here doesn't require an **src**; 2. `myObj.stats` doesn't exist. `myObj.results` is an array, and has two elements that contains `Stats` (watch for the capital **S**). You can get to those `Stats` objects by `myObj.results[0].Stats` and `myObj.results[1].Stats`, or by iterating over `myObj.results` with an iteration function (like `.map()`).

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :)

Comment: Okay. Where should I put the myObj.results[0].Stats?

Comment: Would you mind looking at one of my other projects? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398435/how-can-i-get-data-from-a-json-file-that-is-on-a-different-domain-with-no-header