# How can I get data from a JSON file that is on a different domain with no headers?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am trying to get data from [AWS JSON](https://tepfsail50.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/report/metguv?rptdate=20190807). It is not on my domain and I can't get the data. The error that chrome gives is below Could anyone review my code and give me some tips?

Second, I was using Insomnia just using the link and was able to get the specific data point that I wanted using `$.0.Ed0320`. How do I translate this into JavaScript.

I have tried using a xmlHttpRequest.

Here is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Ed0320": "8.010886",
    "TmStamp": "2019-08-07 15:15:00",
    "Ed0340": "21.15973",
    "Ed0305": "0.2966875",
    "Ed0313": "3.344086"
  },
  {
    "Ed0320": "6.761719",
    "TmStamp": "2019-08-07 15:10:00",
    "Ed0340": "17.47292",
    "Ed0305": "0.2349026",
    "Ed0313": "2.789934"
  }
]
```

Here is my XML:

```
function reqListener() {
     // parse the the data
     var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
     // create an array from the required data (result.Stats -> watch the capital 'S')
     var mappedData = data[0];
     // display data
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = mappedData.join()
}
function loadData(url) {
     var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
     oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
     oReq.open("GET", url);
     oReq.send();
}
```

Chrome gives the error of    `Access to XMLHttpRequest at <fileName> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

```
function calcUVI(Ed0305, Ed0313, Ed0320, Ed0340){
                total305=(Ed0305*0.8058)
                total313=(Ed0313*0.0887)
                total320=(Ed0320*0.0324)
                total340=(Ed0340*0.0131)
                UVI = total305 + total313 + total320 + total340
                return UVI
            }
```

Also, I would like to change the url based on this function below. Is there a way to input this into the fetch?

```
function changeText(){
                var d = new Date();
                var year = d.getFullYear();
                var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                var day = d.getDate();
                if (month <= 9){
                    month = '0'+month;
                }
                if (day <= 9){
                    day = '0'+day;
                }
                var dateTotal = year + month + day;
                url = "https://cors-escape.herokuapp.com/https://tepfsail50.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/report/metguv?rptdate=" + dateTotal;
                console.log(url);
            }
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I am really new to all of this.

Comment: Hi! This is quite late here, so I can only look at it more thoroughly tomorrow. But I have a question: can you get the data from the **AWS** link, and have only problem parsing it, or you cannot even get the data with JavaScript?

Comment: I edited my answer with a second snippet (I deleted the old comments and added new ones)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## 1. Fetching the data

I'm not quite sure, what you want to achieve, but here's a snippet, that

1. Makes a request to **cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com** to "proxy" the query of the "target" URL
2. Returns a **Promise** from the queried URL, so we can wait for it to resolve in other parts of the code
3. Filter and map the resulting data - I didn't understand what data would you like to get from the resulting array and how did you want to handle that data

```js
// self calling function to wrap the await in
// an async function (so the await is not "top level")
(async function() {
  // waiting for the returned Promise to resolve
  // if you console.log() the data constant, then you'll
  // see that it's the full dataset (in JSON format) that you
  // got from simply calling the AWS URL
  const data = await fetchURL()

  // filtering the array for objects that have a key of "Ed0320"
  const filtered = data.filter(e => typeof e['Ed0320'] !== "undefined")
  // mapping the values of all "Ed0320" from the array
  const mapped = data.map(e => e['Ed0320'])

  // simple output, so you can check the values
  console.log(filtered);
  console.log(mapped)
})();

// fetch request using cors-anywhere
function fetchURL() {
  // creating the URL to be called:
  // first part is cors-anywhere, second part is
  // the real URL to be queried
  const url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://tepfsail50.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/report/metguv?rptdate=20190807'

  // returning a Promise, as fetch() is an asynchron
  // function, so it's not resolved immediately
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // using fetch() instead of the XMLHttpRequest()
    // fetch returns a Promise, so you can use .then() and
    // .catch() chained after it
    fetch(url)
      .then(r => {
        resolve(r.json())
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
  })
}
```

So, your code had **CORS** issues (CORS: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)), that had to be handled before you could get the data. I used the **cors-anywhere on Heroku** to overcome this obstacle. You can set your cors-anywhere service by installing the module from npm (here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere).

## 2. EDIT: Processing the data

The answer is edited as the question was expanded with more information.

This new snippet does calculate the **UVI** based on the results from the API (the URL is generated dynamically based on current date).

Please note:

- you can make all your functions shorter (like don't create variables for values that you only need for one calculation, where you only return the result - e.g. current date string or the UVI calculation)
- the "creation" of the date string is modified: I used string interpolation and **('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)** to force two digits long months and days
- when you create (design) a function try to keep it simple - it should do only one thing (so don't create a function that generates current date string and attaches it to the query string. Maintenance will be much easier this way.
- the **calcUVI()** function receives its parameters via destructuring the array element it's called with. Get familiar with destructuring - it's not that hard, and makes your code easier to read and understand. (You can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
(async function() {
  // modified fetchURL() - the URL parameter is passed to
  // the API query function
  const data = await fetchURL(urlToQuery())

  // calling calcUVI() function with the first data
  // entry of the data array
  const UVI = calcUVI(data[0])

  // displaying result in the console
  console.log("UVI:", UVI)
})();

function fetchURL(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // the url parameter is received when the function
    // is called - it's not a constant anymore
    fetch(url)
      .then(r => {
        resolve(r.json())
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
  })
}

// creating and returning the API URL dynamically -
// date string is added
function urlToQuery() {
  // the query URL base is here - and the date string
  // at the end is created dynamically
  return `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://tepfsail50.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/report/metguv?rptdate=${getDateString()}`
}

// creating and returning the date string
function getDateString() {
  const d = new Date();
  return `${d.getFullYear()}${('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}${('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)}`
}

// calcUVI receives the parameters destructured from
// the first element of the array (it's called in
// the main async function)
function calcUVI({
  Ed0305,
  Ed0313,
  Ed0320,
  Ed0340
}) {
  // no need to store these elements as variables, as the single
  // Ed... values are not used anymore in the process (a
  // total is returned, so just add them up)
  return Ed0305 * 0.8058 + Ed0313 * 0.0887 + Ed0320 * 0.0324 + Ed0340 * 0.0131
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to get the most recent data set (which is the first entry) and I need to input those data points into an equation. I loaded the function into the original question

Comment: Very much appreciated. You have been a great help on both of my questions.

Comment: I'm happy if I could help.

Comment: How would I go about using multiple links in the Promise function? I have another project that I have 7 URL's that I need to use CORS to get the JSON data on it.

Comment: It depends on how you want to use your data. If the order of receiving those data doesn't count, then you could use **Promise.all()**. If you want to get them in a certain order, then you could use **async-await** syntax in a loop.

Comment: It depends on how you want to use your data. If the order of receiving those data doesn't count, then you could use **Promise.all()**. If you want to get them in a certain order, then you could use **async-await** syntax in a loop.